# Do I *have to* flatten all hierarchical component declarations in React.JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering what the canonical method is for creating a dynamic select component in React. Do I *have to* create a separate component that returns options as per the code below in order to be able to customize the value through props for each entry, and then include these into a separate select component?

```
class ListEntry extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    return(
      <option value={this.props.ovalue}>{this.props.ovalue}</option>
    )
  }
}


class SomeList extends React.Component {
  genstuff = (n) => {
    var theEntries = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      theEntries.push(<ListEntry ovalue={Math.random().toString()} />)
    };
    return(theEntries)
  }

  render = () => {
    var entries = this.genstuff(10);
    return(
      <select>
        {entries}
        <ListEntry ovalue="a basic entry"/>
        <ListEntry ovalue="another"/>
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there another "accepted" way to do this within the SomeList component itself? If so, what are the advantages, disadvantages?

I have also used this technique (successfully) for svg elements so the above question applies too:

```
class SmallCircle extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    return(
      <circle cx={this.props.scx} cy={this.props.scy} r="5" 
        stroke="blue" fill="dodgerblue" strokeWidth="2"/>)
  }
}


class SomeSvg extends React.Component {

  randomCoords = (n, domain) => {
    let xs = [...Array(n).keys()].map(i=> {
      return {
        "i": i,
        "x": Math.floor(Math.random() * domain + 1).toString(),
        "y": Math.floor(Math.random() * domain + 1).toString()
      }
    })
    return(xs)
  }

  render = () => {
    var svgcoords = this.randomCoords(5000, 700);
    var thecircles = svgcoords.map(xy => <SmallCircle key={xy.i.toString() + xy.x.toString() + xy.y.toString()} 
        scx={xy.x} scy={xy.y} />);
    return(
      <svg width="700" height="700">
        {thecircles}
        <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="100" stroke="orange" strokeWidth="7" fill="grey" />
        <circle cx="700" cy="700" r="100" stroke="green" strokeWidth="7" fill="grey" />
        <circle cx="1" cy="700" r="100" stroke="red" strokeWidth="7" fill="grey" />
        <circle cx="700" cy="1" r="100" stroke="blue" strokeWidth="7" fill="grey" />
        <SmallCircle scx="200" scy="200" />
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

So basically my question is, does React require you to "unwrap" (ie flatten) hierarchical component structures into multiple granular top-level components all the time?

Here is the output, btw:

[image]

EDIT: I do realise I haven't included a "key" for each select entry and it's complaining in the console, but the question isn't affected by this.

Comment: Can you try to reformulate your question please? I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: No I think it's perfectly clear. "Flattening" a hierachical data structure, in computer science, means parsing it down into a vector (ie an array). That's what I'm asking about react. I have hierarchical display elements, but I'm having to declare them in a flattened form. I'm asking if this is the canonical way of doing things, as in, do I have to declare internal elements externally to the component, in a serial form, as opposed to creating sub-components within the components themselves. see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70743/what-does-flatten-mean

Comment: If you wish to flatten, you can assign an additional prop called "parentID" to your list entry that helps in easily referencing it. If you wish not to flatten it, then you might want to a prop to your list entry with "children".

If you think I'm somewhere close to what you wish to achivie then I could probably help with an answer. I propose something along these lines. For *Flattened:* options `<ListEntry parentID="root" />`  for *Heirarchial*: `<ListEntry children={() => return <AnotherList>} />`

Comment: Seem you need [stateless](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

Comment: Do you mean that all your circles are supposed to be organized hierarchically ? Maybe you can show in your question what kind of hierarchy they should have.

Comment: I have given two examples. The first is circles in an SVG, and the second is options in a select. In both cases, I must create a sub-component OUTSIDE the svg component, or OUTSIDE the select statement. This seems to be the only way to create sub-components in REACT. So basically the "natural" html hierarchical paradigm is transformed into a flattened serial paradigm. I don't know why this is so difficult to understand. Please only attempt to answer if you have a formal background in computer science, and experience of data structures across different programming languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, React does not require you to do that.
If you wanted to, you could put all your React code in 1 giant component.

So, why not do that? There's many reasons actually: readability, reusability, testability, maintainability, etc.

Meaning: you create seperate components when you need certain logic to stand on its own. In your question, you have ListEntry as a seperate component. Why? If you dont use that component anywhere else in your code, you can just put that logic inside SomeList if you wanted to.

I think the key to your question is this: you dont need to inherit from React.Component if you dont use any of its logic. Basic 'stateless components' can be written as a function:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    (...some logic...)
    return <option>{ props.value }</option>;
}
```

Or, ES6 equivalent:

```
const MyComponent = props => { 
    (...some logic...)
    return <option>{ props.value }</option>;
}
```

or, if you dont need any logic in the rendering at all:

```
const MyComponent = props => <option>{ props.value }</option>;
```

So, you could just define this function in your components `render` (or in the function body for stateless components), like so:

```
class SomeList extends Component {
    render() {
        const ListEntry = props => <option>{ props.value }</option>;
        return (
            <select>
                { [...Array(10).keys()].map(x => (
                    <ListEntry key={x} value={Math.random()} />
                ))}
                <ListEntry value="basic" />
                <ListEntry value="another" />
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

Here, the code for our `ListEntry` component is defined in the SomeList components' render. *(disclaimer: I don't think `render` is the best place for this tho, it's just to illustrate the point)*.
Though, I don't really see the point in doing so. Since ListEntry doesnt contain any logic, why not use `<option>` directly instead of ListEntry?
It could be a simple as:

```
const SomeList = () => {
    return (
        <select>
            { [...Array(10).keys()].map(index => (
                <option key={index}>{ Math.random() }</option>
            ))}
            <option>Basic</option>
            <option>Another</option>
        </select>
    );
};
```

As for your SVG example: if you take the above and create functions for the components you need, it could be written like this:

```
const SomeSvg = () => {
    const SmallCircle = props => (
        <circle {...props} r="5" stroke="blue" fill="dodgerblue" strokeWidth="2" />
    );

    const BigCircle = props => (
        <circle {...props} r="100" strokeWidth="7" fill="grey" />
    );

    const randomCoords = (n, domain) => [...Array(n).keys()].map(() => ({
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * domain + 1),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * domain + 1)
    }));

    return (
        <svg width="700" height="700">
            { randomCoords(5000, 700).map((xy, i) => <SmallCircle key={i} cx={xy.x} cy={xy.y} />) }
            <BigCircle cx="1" cy="1" stroke="orange" />
            <BigCircle cx="700" cy="700" stroke="green" />
            <BigCircle cx="1" cy="700" stroke="red" />
            <BigCircle cx="700" cy="1" stroke="blue" />
            <SmallCircle cx="200" cy="200" />
        </svg>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't have any opinion on how much granular your component structures should be. It might be one component with some props or multiple components.

So Select component can be something like follows.

```js
class Select extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select>
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        {this.props.options.map(option =>
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.text}
          </option>
        )}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

You can simply provide a JavaScript array as `option` and it will work nicely.

```js
var options = [
  { value: 'one', text: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', text: 'Two' }
];

<Select options={options} />
```

Now let's say we got a new requirement to highlight some options of one Select component of your application based on some criteria. We got few options here.

The simplest option would be writing another similar component with highlighting logic. But this will duplicate most of our code and make it hard to maintain.

Another option is to pass an additional prop and conditionally enable highlighting logic based on the prop. Again, this isn't scalable. When we get several new requirements like this it will be hard to maintain our component's code and understand the interface of it.

However, if we make our component based on multiple composable components it will be easy to customize your component based on different requirements. In this case, we can introduce a `highlight` prop to `Option` component and simply conditionally pass the prop based on the criteria.

```js
class Option extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <option
        value={this.props.value}
        className={this.prop.highlight ? "highlight" : ""}
      >
        {this.props.text}
      </option>
    );
  }
}

class Select extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select className="my-select">
        {this.props.children} // render children of Select tag
      </select>
    );
  }
}

class HighLightingSelect extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Select>
        {this.props.options((option, index) =>
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.value} highlight={index % 2}>
            {option.text}
          </Option>
        )}
      </Select>
    );
  }
}
```

The idea here is it's totally up to you to decide how much granularity you want in your component structures. It can be one component or a dozen of components which need be composed together to get the expected result.

If you make it more granular, it will be easy to customize and reuse your code in different situations. Especially, React promote [composition over inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) for code reuse. So granularity is key to reusability in React.

But having multiple components will make it harder to understand and use your component in simple scenarios.

Comment: This is an excellent answer too, @Tharaka Wijenbandara, but I must award to only one and the other answer just got an extra point. Thank you anyway. Very useful.